# How to keep certain values of a categorical variable in regession model

Tags: r, linear-regression, data-analysis

This is the model:

```
model2<-lm(resp1 ~ pred3 + pred4 + pred6 + pred7, data = hwdat)
summary(model2)
```

[image]

As you can see, if I only want to keep the predict variable which P-Value is less than 0.01, but `pred7` is a categorical variable, how to modified the regression model to just keep `pred7Grade B` and `pred7Grade D`?

Comment: I think you'd have to drop the rows containing those "Grade C" values for `pred7`, or set those values to `NA` (depending on how you are treating `NA` values). E.g. - `model2 <- lm(resp1 ~ pred3 + pred7, data = hwdat, subset=pred7 != "Grade C")` - i'm unsure if that is wise statistically however.

Comment: You are right, I shouldn't drop it.

Comment: In factor variables, the first level is generally dropped from the matrix to make it full rank. Here, I assume there is a level for `Grade A` which is not visible because of this. If you really wanted to remove `Grade C`, then you could do something like: `hwdat$pred7 <- factor( hwdat$pred7, levels = paste('Grade', c('C', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'E')))`. One thing you'll have to take care of is this modification will have to be done when making any predictions as well.

Comment: The plan suggested by Rohit would give you an output that would set the C level as the baseline for the estimates of the other levels. It would not "remove" the data  from the model estimation process or remove the influence of the data points with level C. It would change the output so the C level did not appear but would rather be hidden or subsumed into the "Intercept" value. If this were a "control" or reference status it might be useful.

Comment: Thank you guys, very helpful!